# Añadir una propiedad y dos métodos a la clase Textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

¿Es posible añadir propiedades y métodos de extensión a la clase `Textbox` siendo est@s únicos del objeto en cuestión?

He seguido [este ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697648/how-can-i-add-a-new-function-or-property-on-textbox-classs-text-property), en el cual mediante una clase estática es posible saber, por ejemplo, si el objeto al que lanzas el mensaje es nulo o no, pero en mi caso, me gustaría poder mediante una propiedad extra, asignar a esta el valor false o true en función de unas características concretas, y ademas posteriormente saber en que estado se encuentra esa propiedad.

```
    namespace ExtensionMethods
    {
         public static class MyExtensions
         {
              public static bool IsTextEmpty(this Textbox txtBox)
              {
                  return string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox.Text);
              }
          }   
     }
```

El ejemplo del enlace no me vale pues al utilizar una clase estática no puedo obtener valores independientes para diferentes objetos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar las extensiones que requiera la clase `TextBox` pero ten en cuenta que extensiones no alteran la estructura de la clase, solo la *extienden* en términos coloquiales no podrás agregarle `propiedades` adicionales, pero extienden la `clase` para que pueda invocar `métodos` que no están declarados en la `clase`.

Si lo que realmente deseas es agregar una propiedad, tendrías que crear una clase que herede de `TextBox` y agregarle la propiedad que requieras

```
public class MiTextBox:TextBox
{
//propiedades adicionales
}
```

Saludos, espero te sirva

Comment: Hola, el problema es que estoy en WPF y si creo una clase que herede de textbox después no me deja utilizarla en el XAML, seguramente no este haciendo algo bien...
No se que me da que es un tema de espacios de nombres... 
¿Si creo mi clase MiTextBox y deseo utilizarla en diferentes vistas en diferentes espacios de nombres hay que hacer algo especial en el XAML?

Comment: Si, se puede utilizar en xaml, puedes hacer otra pregunta relacionada ese tema, tienes que incluir el namespace de tu control en el xaml y asignarle un name para que lo uses como tag al momento de crear objetos

Answer (score 1):

Los métodos de una clase son comunes a todas las instancias de la clase (incluyendo instancias de subclases).

Tienes dos opciones:

- No preocuparte. Si añades a una clase un método nuevo, ningún otro código hará llamadas a ese método, así que será tu código cliente el que use esa funcionalidad y puedes controlar que solo se llame al método para las instancias que elijas.
- Extender: Si por algún motivo eso no te va bien, extiende la clase `TextBox` en una nueva clase y añade el método en la subclase. [Aquí tienes algo de información de la MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/control-type-recommendations).

En cuanto a la parte de "asignar un valor", ¿qué hay de malo con?

```
public static bool setTextEmpty(this Textbox txtBox, bool textEmpty)
{
   if (textEmpty) {
      txtBox.Text = null;
   }
}
```